# Filtering Elastic search result with must and match giving unexpected result

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-rails, chewy-gem, elasticsearch-ruby

```
{
  "body": {
    "query": {
      "bool": {
        "must": {
          "match": {
            "_id": "24"
          }
        },
        "should": [
          {
            "term": {
              "draft_id": "draft_11"
            }
          },
          {
            "term": {
              "draft_id": "non_draft"
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**result contains below information**

```
{
  "_id": "24",
  "name": "xyz",
  "draft_id": "draft_312"
}
```

**Requirement**

I wan to filter record based on:

- id must match
- And draft_id should be either `non_draft` or `draft_11`

OR in simple words

`id = 24 AND (draft_id = "non_draft" OR draft_id = "draft_11")`

And if you see the result, it only matches id, but not draft_id field.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to move your should clause inside must_clause. Only clauses in must get "AND" among themselves

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "match": {
            "_id": "24"
          }
        },
        {
          "bool": {
            "should": [
              {
                "term": {
              "draft_id": "draft_11"
            }
              },
              {
             "term": {
              "draft_id": "draft_11"
            }   
              }
            ]
          }
        },
        {
          "query_string": {
            "default_field": "FIELD",
            "query": "this AND that OR thus"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Also, if I want to include query_string in above example?

Comment: @przbadu It is part or OR or another AND  id = 24 AND (draft_id = "non_draft" OR draft_id = "draft_11")

Comment: yes part of my AND query, because query_string is required field. Thanks a lot, now I have working solution. appreciated!!